# Link JUnit ParentRunner to Clojure source locations

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, clojure

I've created a custom ParentRunner test runner in JUnit that I am using to run a set of dynamically generated tests - specifically running some declarations within a Clojure namespace. Source code for the runner is here:

https://github.com/mikera/cljunit/blob/master/src/main/java/mikera/cljunit/NamespaceRunner.java

I'd like to somehow link the test results to the Clojure source file locations so that IDE integration works properly (e.g. double click on a test result in Eclipse to see the corresponding Clojure source).

Is it possible to configure a ParentRunner to link to custom source locations?